# Book recommendation - The Fibonacci Sequence and the Golden Ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, book-recommendation

What book do you think gives the best explanation on the Fibonacci Sequence and the Golden Ratio?

I am thinking to read "The Golden Ratio: The Story of Phi, the World's Most Astonishing Number" by Mario Livio. The title is very enticing, but many reviews are not in favour of it. Are there any prerequisites needed to grasp it's concept?

Comment: What is "best" for you will depend very much on your level of mathematical preparation.  Without knowing that, it's hard to make a recommendation.

Comment: I am an undergraduate maths student in 1st year.

Comment: You might look at [this article](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_05_07.html).